# LiquibasePro don't generate package, packagebody and other things in the changeLog file

Tags: oracle, liquibase, liquibase-pro

I use LiquibasePro and liquibase pro don't generate package, packagebody, fuction and etc. into changeLog file.
How to fix this?

Comment: My DB is oracle 11.2.0.2.0, NLS_CHARACTERSET = AL32UTF8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a trial license? That would be the first thing to check. If you do have a license and have included it in the `liquibase.properties` file, you should be contacting Liquibase Pro support using the email address that you received when you signed up for the trial rather than asking here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes, i have a trial pro liicense. So if i have a trial pro license i cant use pro version function?

Comment: If you have a trial license and it isn't working as expected, contact Liquibase support (which I will see, along with the whole Datical support team) and we can figure out what the issue is.